# How to retrieve selected value from the dropdown list in asp.net and store it in session variable?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, data-binding, session-variables

The dropdown list is showing data from database, but how to retrieve the selected value and store it in a session variable?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Eval` or `Bind` methods to Databind the SelectedValue in the dropdownlist

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" 
    SelectedValue='<%# Bind("ID") %>'  />
```